# Evaluating data and displaying it on chart control using C#

Tags: c#, statistics, analysis

Good day everyone.

I have a type called User.

```
public struct User {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I have an array of this type.

```
public User[] users;
```

The array contains:

```
Index | ID | Name    | Country
0      1    Smith     United States
1      2    Aki       Japan
2      3    Lisa      United States 
3      4    Adam      Sweden
4      5    Geert     Germany
5      6    Hido      Japan
```

How would I find out how many users are from each country in C#?

```
United states - 2
Japan         - 2
Sweden        - 1
Germany       - 1
```

I want to evaluate this information so I can display on a chart control. I'm sure there is information online for what I'm trying to do but I do not know exactly how to phrase it.. Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

---

**Update:**

I've done the following and it works:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> countries = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (User user in users) {
        if (!countries.Keys.Contains(user.Country)) {
            countries.Add(user.Country, 1);
        }
        else {
            countries[user.Country]++;
        }
    }
```

However, I believe it is not the best way... I want to see alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you use CarbineCoders answer with `group.Key` instead of `group.Country`

```
public User[] users;

var countryCount= users.ToList().GroupBy(n => n.Country).
                     Select(group =>
                         new
                         {
                             Country= group.Key,
                             Count = group.Count()
                         });
```

Comment: Yes this fixed the error, the code works now. Thank you and @CarbineCoder .

Comment: @Kathi Everyone starts with Ground zero. If you keep giving such a valuable answers, soon you will breach into higher reputation ranks. I think your first milestone should be scoring a century ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Linq

```
var results = from U in users
              group U by U.Country into g
              select new { Country = g.Key, Total = g.count };
```

Comment: **Error:** `'IGrouping<string, Form1.User>' does not contain a definition for 'count' and no extension method 'count' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<string, Form1.User>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`